# Prove that mean coordinate modulo of a random walking point is $O(\sqrt n)$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-walk

Consider a point on a coordinate line. The starting coordinate of it is $0$, and it performs $n$ walks, each one shifts the point either by $1$ to the left or by $1$ to the right. Each direction is chosen with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Prove that the mean coordinate modulo is $O(\sqrt n)$.

My approach is as follows: let $\xi$ be the coordinate modulo of the point after $n$ walks. $$P(\xi=a)=\begin{cases}0, & n \text{ and } a \text{ are of different parity or }a>n \\ 2\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{a+\frac{n-a}{2}}, & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Explanation for $2\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{a+\frac{n-a}{2}}$: $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is the probability of a fixed sequence of $n$ walks happening, for $a$ to be the final coordinate there needs to be $a+\frac{n-a}{2}$ walks left (or right), therefore the binomial is the amount of walk sequences that result in the final coordinate being $a$.

$$\mathbb E\xi=\sum\limits_{a=0}^n aP(\xi=a)$$

With both even and uneven $n$ Wolfram shows that $\mathbb E\xi=O(\sqrt n)$, but I'm looking for a more elegeant proof.

Comment: Note that $n = E[\xi^2]  \ge E[|\xi|]^2$.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal I do not follow why $n=E[\xi^2]$

Comment: just expand $\xi^2$, the squared terms contribute 1 and the cross terms have expectation 0.

Comment: I don't know if you consider this elegant, but this follows essentially from the central limit theorem (which actually tells you that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{E}[\xi_n/\sqrt{n}]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$). This gives the corresponding lower bound of $\Theta(\sqrt{n})$ and actually the asymptotic constant.