# Prove that mean maximum coordinate of a random walking point is $O(\sqrt n)$

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, random-walk

This is a question similar to [my previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589779/prove-that-mean-coordinate-modulo-of-a-random-walking-point-is-o-sqrt-n).

Consider a point on a coordinate line. The starting coordinate of it is $0$, and it performs $n$ walks, each one shifts the point either by $1$ to the left or by $1$ to the right. Each direction is chosen with probability $p=\frac{1}{2}$. Prove that the mean maximum coordinate is $O(\sqrt n)$.

I've considered representing the maximum coordinate as a random variable $\xi=\max_{t=1\ldots n} \sum_{i=1}^t X_i$, where $X_i$ is $\pm 1$, depending on which direction was chosen at the $i$-th step, but $\mathbb E\xi\not=\max_{t=1\ldots n} \mathbb E\sum_{i=1}^t X_i$ as far as I know.

Edit: I have made some progress:
$$\mathbb E\xi=\sum_{i=1}^n P(\xi\geq i)=\sum_{i=0}^n P(\xi > i)=n-\sum_{i=1}^n P(\xi\leq i)=n-\sum_{i=0}^n\prod_{j=i}^n P(\xi_j\leq i)$$
$\xi_j\leq i$ means at least $\frac{j-i}{2}$ walks were made to the left $(-1)$, therefore:
$$P(\xi_j\leq i)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{j-i}{2}}\binom{j}{\frac{j-i}{2}}$$
$$\mathbb E\xi=n-\sum_{i=0}^n\prod_{j=i}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{j-i}{2}}\binom{j}{\frac{j-i}{2}}$$

Comment: For the distance after $n$ steps you have the exact formula and the $\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi}}$ asymptotic here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html obtained by elementary means -except perhaps for the asymptotic which uses the multiplication formula for the gamma function. Then we have to prove that the expectation of the final distance is at least that of the maximum. Conditional on $\xi_n=M$ $E(|S_n|)=M$, then i think the result follows from the law of total expectation -and perhaps the fact that those expectations are increasing in $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing this directly is likely to be quite challenging.

Likely the easiest approach is by appealing to [Donsker's Invariance Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem), which would enable you to carry the equivalent result for Brownian motion to the discrete setting.

The result for Brownian motion, along with references, is stated on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Running_maximum) as having the closed form:

$$ \mathbf E \left[ \max_{0\leq s \leq t} B_s\right] = \sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}.$$

You may also want to look at the [Law of the Iterated Logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm), and its derivation for inspiration. This regards the limsup of a random walk/Brownian motion and not the maximum at a fixed time.

---

**Sketch Proof**

Let $S_n$ denote the simple random walk
$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k,$$
where the $X_k$ are i.i.id with $\mathbf P[X_k = 1] = \mathbf P[X_k = -1] = \frac12$.

We define a continuous time analogue of $S_n$ by interpolating between each step; that is for $t \in \mathbf R$

$$S(t) = S_{\lfloor t \rfloor} + (t - \lfloor t \rfloor )S_{\lfloor t \rfloor +1}.$$

To apply Donsker's Invariance Principle, we consider a copy of this scaled to stay in the interval $[0,1]$

$$ S^*_n(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} S(nt), \qquad t \in [0,1].$$

And we can write the expectation that we are interested in as

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbf E \left[ \max_{0 \leq k \leq n} S_k \right] =
\mathbf E \left[ \max_{0 \leq k \leq n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} S_k \right] = \mathbf E \left[ \max_{0 \leq s \leq 1} S^*_n(s) \right].$$

Donsker's theorem implies that the process $S_n^*$ converges in distribution to Brownian motion. One of the definitions for this type of convergence is that it is equivalent to convergence of expectations of continuous bounded functions (the Portmanteau Lemma).

The maximum function is continuous, but **not** bounded so we cannot instantly apply the lemma. Since this is a sketch/heuristic I will simply show that if this condition did hold, we'd be able to state

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\mathbf E \left[ \max_{0 \leq k \leq n} S_k \right] \rightarrow \mathbf E \left[ \max_{0 \leq s \leq 1} B_s \right] = \sqrt{\frac2\pi}$$

To be clear - this last step is sketchy since the maximum is not bounded so we cannot apply the Portmanteau lemma. A more formal proof is given [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/205B/bmbook.pdf) in Chapter 5, section 4.

Comment: As far as I understand, Donsker's invariance principle allows to get $B_i$, where $i\in\mathbb Z$, instead of $B_s; s\in\mathbb R$. However, $B_s$ has normally distributed increments, while I am interested in increments of $\pm 1$. Does the same principle also deal with that?

Comment: Not quite - Donsker's theorem takes the random walk (taking $\pm 1$ steps, though generalises too), and interpolates it and scales it to be on $[0,1]$. I've added a sketch proof. If this is helpful, can I please ask that you accept the answer.